# Python: Multi-Dimensional Array Using ctypes?

Tags: python, ctypes

How do I define a multi-dimensional float array using `ctypes` in `python`?

Is there a limitation to the number of dimensions that can be defines?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one quick-and-dirty method:

```
>>> A = ((ctypes.c_float * 10) * 10)
>>> a = A()
>>> a[5][5]
0.0
```